# Performing Segue between container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I’m developing for the iPhone and have a table view embedded in a `ContainerView`, to enable me to display iAds as per Apple’s sample code.

When a user selects a row I want to segue to a new table view, also embedded in a `ContainerView`, so that the second view continues to display ads.

When selecting a row in the first table, `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and the `viewDidLoad` method of the second view executes, but the view does not appear, and the CPU goes to 100%.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated. I've searched here & on Apple's developer forums, but can't find anything to resolve this problem.

Comment: Use Xcode's debugger and go step by step.

Comment: `FirstViewContainer` contains a `UITableView` inside a `UIView` and 'iAd'. The `SecondViewController` contains the same structure, right?

Comment: the_UB - Yes, structure is as you describe.

Comment: vomako - I only have one line of code to run the segue & a couple of NSLogs to show what methods are being called, but had forgotten Apple's iAd code (BannerViewController.m). I have a loop in their code where view layoutSubViews is called from viewDidLayoutSubviews.  I will try & figure out what I can change to resolve it, thanks for the prompt.